# Auto approve revert pull request in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

Is there a way to auto approve reverts? Particularly if they are recent / have no conflicts?

For other changes, I want to require reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write your own gitHub Action, based on:

- [`ridedott/merge-me-action`](https://github.com/ridedott/merge-me-action), which shows [how to trigger an "accept and merge"](https://github.com/ridedott/merge-me-action/blob/056d84042a7ca7852bb859fb13138cf703d4424b/src/common/merge.ts#L79-L114)
- [`xt0rted/block-autosquash-commits-action`](https://github.com/xt0rted/block-autosquash-commits-action), which shows how to [examine each commit message](https://github.com/xt0rted/block-autosquash-commits-action/blob/main/pullRequestChecker.js#L7-L26): in your case, you would be looking for commits with "`Revert ...`" in them.